# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') ERROR!

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me podría ayudar por favor no se como solucionar este error

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor agrega el código y error en texto, ya que las imágenes no permiten la correcta lectura del mismo, explica mas sobre el problema, revisa [ask]. Recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error es que estás definiendo los valores del ID dentro de el campo name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chek_bk">
```

cuando debería estar en el campo ID (porque estás haciendo un `getElementById()`)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chek_bk" value="...">
```

sería el correcto. Esto tienes que hacerlo con  todos.